# dotnet core web api DELETE call 404 error after deploy to IIS 8.5 server

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Calling delete from angular front end.  The error shows:

```
Http failure response for http://devserver.us/MyApp/api/additive/3: 404 Not Found
```

Delete method in angular client:

```
  onDelete(additive: Additive) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this additive?")) {
      var id = additive.AdditiveId;
      this._additiveService.delete(id).subscribe(result => {
        var ad = result;
        console.log(id + " has been deleted.");
        this.refresh();
      }, error => console.log(error));
    }
  }
```

Additive Service:

```
  private url = this.baseUrl + "api/additive/";

  delete(id: number): Observable<Additive> {
    return this.http.delete<Additive>(this.url+id, { withCredentials: true }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Web Api controller:

```
    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var deleteid = id;

        return NoContent();
    }
```

The controller inherits from a base api controller:

```
public class AdditiveController : BaseApiController
{
    ....

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BaseApiController : Controller
{
      ......
```

It works fine in localhost but after deploying to dev server (IIS 10) all the GETs work but the DELETE returns 404 Not Found.  URL to the controller is correct.

web config allows all verbs:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

I checked the stdout log and event viewer, but they contain no data.

How do I 1. Get a detailed error message or 2. Fix this?

Comment: `this.url+id` what is the value of this.url once application is deployed to the dev server? Is this.url ending with `/`

Comment: Does your CORS settings allow requests from your dev domain?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - I have added the url variable to the 'service' section. Yes it ends with /.

Comment: @Brad -  I have not added CORS to the app. This is my first API so I am not very familiar with CORS but it was my understanding that I would only need to add it if I got the "no Access-Control-Allow-Origin error". Is this incorrect?

Comment: @BattlFrog - Have you tried executing DELETE request using postman or fiddler? Also, is your application is deployed as a sub-application "MyApp" because url is http://devserver.us/MyApp

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - I have tried fiddler, it returns the same 404 error with no further info.  Postman says it does not do windows auth.

Comment: @BattlFrog - Do you have any other Delete endpoint defined in the same controller? Also for testing, rename your method to "DeleteById" and keep the [HttpDelete] attribute as it is.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - No other delete in the controller.  I changed the name, no change.  Works on localhost, 404 error after deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in the applicationHost config file on the server.  DELETE had to be explicitly allowed, it was not.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what you added exactly in applicationHost.config ? And do you just go with an "IISreset" right after ?

Comment: Sorry, this was 4 years and 2 jobs ago. I no longer have access to that code.

Comment: Ahah np, I knew the topic was quite old and had little hope anyway. Thanks for answering.